# Frigidaire Dryer with error E64

Tags: appliances, dryer

My dryer is giving me an error code e64. It is an affinity Frigidaire dryer. They dryer heats up just fine. It cuts off after 10-20 minutes of running with this error. The "Dryer Tech Data Sheet" describes E64 as follows:

> E64 - Heater Open Circuit - Heating Element or wiring defective -
>   Check heater coils and connections for open circuits. Replace heater
>   and or wiring and retest.

My theory is that the thermostat has gone bad and is stuck "open" and never cuts off the heating element. Eventually the unit gets hot enough for the high limit sensor to get tripped and the dryer throws the error. Does that sound plausible? What else might be going on here?

Comment: Did you Google, as their already seems to be websites that address this specific issue, e.g. [this one](http://therandomfix.blogspot.com/2013/07/frigidaire-affinity-e64-error.html).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the heating coil. I was able to test resistance with a multi-meter and saw that there was a broken circuit in one of the 3 legs of the heating coil. At first I crimped the broken end together, but later replaced the part.

Googling:

> test dryer heating element multimeter

will yield good results.